# Split Pandas Series to Multiple Column by Substring

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to split a DataFrame Series with likely regex into multiple columns.

**Replicable code:**

```
pd.DataFrame({"Animals":["(Cat1, Dog1)", "(Cat1, Dog2)", "(Cat1, Dog3)", "(Cat2, Dog1)", "(Cat2, Dog2)", "(Cat2, Dog3)"]})
```

**Input Table:**

[image]

**Desired Table:**

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:

Per comments, Shubham's solution is the cleanest:

```
df[['Animals1', 'Animals2']] = df['Animals'].str.extract(r'(\w+), (\w+)')
```

You can also use `replace` to get rid of parenthses and spaces and then `split(',')` with `expand=True` to create new columns:

```
df[['Animal1', 'Animal2']] = (df['Animals'].replace(['\(', '\)', '\s+'], '', regex=True)
                              .str.split(',', expand=True))
df
Out[1]: 
        Animals  Animal1  Animal2
0  (Cat1, Dog1)     Cat1     Dog1
1  (Cat1, Dog2)     Cat1     Dog2
2  (Cat1, Dog3)     Cat1     Dog3
3  (Cat2, Dog1)     Cat2     Dog1
4  (Cat2, Dog2)     Cat2     Dog2
5  (Cat2, Dog3)     Cat2     Dog3
```

Comment: Try `extract` `df[['Animals1', 'Animals2']] = df['Animals'].str.extract(r'(\w+), (\w+)')` ;)

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Thank you! I didn't realize you could extract into two columns simultaneously. I was going to use `extract()` but on two separate lines. I guess, specifying multiple capture groups is what makes this possible.

Comment: Technically we could extract any number of columns provided we have equal number of capturing groups in the `regex` pattern

Comment: Yes, this is a cleaner solution. Please feel free to post it. A lot or people use `str.extract()`, but I have actually never personally seen it used the way you have used it.

Comment: Please feel free to edit your post to include `str.extract` as an alternate solution.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
df[['Animal1', 'Animal2']] = df['Animals'].str[1:-1].str.split(', ', expand=True)
```

---

```
    Animals         Animal1 Animal2
0   (Cat1, Dog1)    Cat1    Dog1
1   (Cat1, Dog2)    Cat1    Dog2
2   (Cat1, Dog3)    Cat1    Dog3
3   (Cat2, Dog1)    Cat2    Dog1
4   (Cat2, Dog2)    Cat2    Dog2
5   (Cat2, Dog3)    Cat2    Dog3
```

Comment: Thank you. In my personal pandas series, I have some substring before the parentheses and therefore the [1:-1] slicing is not dynamic enough as compared to capturing groups with regex. Nonetheless, I was not specific in my question so thank you still!

Answer (score 2):

One way would be:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"Animals":["(Cat1, Dog1)", "(Cat1, Dog2)", "(Cat1, Dog3)", "(Cat2, Dog1)", "(Cat2, Dog2)", "(Cat2, Dog3)"]})
df['Animal1'] = df['Animals'].map(lambda x: x.split(', ')[0][1:])
df['Animal2'] = df['Animals'].map(lambda x: x.split(', ')[1][:-1])
```

Comment: Thank you, the splitting method is slightly less flexible and powerful as compared to regex as it still retains the parenthesis symbol and does not capture groups as accurately. Nonetheless, I have not thought about this so thank you still.